# passing user consent to nested iframe in an amp page

Tags: accelerated-mobile-page

Is there some known possibility to pass user consent (especially on opt-out mode) on content which is nested via amp-iframe?

The iframe content itself contains an common html page so there is no way to use the "block-data-on-consent" attribute.

Maybe there is even an messy way to solve this issue without tweaking too much around.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an amp-iframe within your consent dialog which can send a postMessage with the consent result back to the amp-consent component. See the [amp reference](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-consent#prompt-actions-from-external-consent-ui) for details.

Comment: Not sure if this will work that way... nevertheless i will i give it a try, thx.

Comment: This approach seems only to work, if the amp-iframe is designed particulary to handle the user consent only.... in my case the amp-iframe content is an individual page which handles an nested video player... so this solution seems not to serve as the solution. Anyway thanks for your hint.

Comment: This issue has been solved by using the https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage tool. instead of passing the value into embeded Iframe, the Iframe itself care about the current user consent status.